# What Javascript Programming Patterns Do You Use?

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns

I'm in the process of re-examining a lot of my code, and I keep coming back to the question, "Which pattern should I base all of my JS classes on?"

Some example patterns:
http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/

I ended up with a mix-in approach, with basic pub/sub functionality. I don't use prototype, or the module pattern, I define public/private properties/methods within the constructor.

For example:

```
function ClassName(){
    var _privateVar = 'private';
    this.publicVar = 'public';
    function _privateMethod(){};
    this.publicMethod = function(){};
}
```

What patterns do you often use in JS? For what purpose? Regular websites? Full web app? What made you pick one pattern over another?

Or do you think it matters less than I think it does?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** well, I do use prototype, just not to define all my methods. But I'm leaning towards that approach due to performance? Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it matters less than I think it does. :p

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider

Defining public functions with inner functions is more expensive since you generate a new function for every instantiation of an object. Defining it on the prototype uses a single copy of the methods.

I always use underscores for private methods/properties, as you have, for clarity.

I also use the module pattern to define static private methods within a class. Since they don't need access to the instance, they are only created once.

Comment: +1 for the cost. It may be minimal for a few object instances, but I can't believe how often it's apparently overlooked, and private members/methods are overrated.

Comment: I don't think private members are overrated. However, I think a good compromise is to use the underscore. That way, someone can still hack into someone else's privates, but are aware that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

We use the module pattern at tinyHippos.

Here is a blog post we wrote on the topic [here](http://tinyhippos.com/2010/06/22/modular-programming-patterns-with-javascript/)

Basically you end up with:

```
var nameSpace = {};

// class constructor
nameSpace.SomeClass = function (arg1, arg1) {

    var _privateProperty = "foo";

    function _privateMethod() {}

    // return public methods
    return {
        publicProperty: "bar",
        publicMethod: function  publicMethod() { }
    };

};

var obj = new nameSpace.SomeClass("arg1", "arg2");
```

Comment: How is this different from just defining private inner functions/props and public func on props on 'this'?

Comment: @JuanMendes the `new` keyword is optional in that example. `var obj = namespace.SomeClass("arg1", "arg2");` also works.

Comment: It "kind of" works. Both cases cause `obj instanceof nameSpace.SomeClass` to return false. To me, any pattern for object creation should not break `instanceof`. I posted something about making object construction work with or without `new` that doesn't break `instanceof` http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html